# Android - Passing the main activity around

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activitygroup

I have a several activities in my app. The main activity (activity1) extends ActivityGroup (I need to support 2.2 and above, so I cant use fragments).

The main activity1 creates activity2, which in turn creates activity3. But when creating activity3 I want activity1 to create it, not activity2.

How do you pass the main activity around between activities?

Thanks

Comment: You still can use fragments in 2.2 - havn't you heared about [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)?

Comment: You _can_ use fragments. There is a support library you can download with the SDK manager that brings fragment support to all versions starting from 1.6. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use `startActivityForResult()` in **avtivity1** to statrt **activity2**.

and when you want **activity3** just finish **activity2** and in activity1 override

`onActivityResult()` and start **Activity3**. passing activity instance is not better idea

since that Activity may get killed when at background and thus susceptible to throw an

Exception.